# throw new error"could not find artifacts from "+import_path" from any sources

Tags: solidity, contract-development

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import "./ConvertLib.sol";

contract SimpleAuction{
    event HiggestBidIncreased(address binder,uint amount);
    function bid()payable{
        HiggestBidIncreased(msg.sender,msg.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: what about `ConvertLib` file? it's in the same folder of this contract?

Comment: yes... its already there

Comment: Are you using truffle v4.1.5 on Windows? Then it is a bug https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/885, you can downgrade to v4.1.4 that seems to work.

Comment: truffle v 4.1.3? So, do i have to change the version? Thanks for your reply!